# access vbscript regular expression invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I have an access table with a memo field where data is entered using a form and before the user enters new data, a date is added in the form of (Apr-01). Upon saving, the new data is added at the top. Then I have a function as follows that goes into the field and gets the newest data so it would be at the top:

Example data

```
Apr-01 - new data
Mar-09 - old data
etc
```

Function to get the latest:

```
Public Function GetLatest(text As String) As String
    If (IsNull(text)) Then
        GetLatest = ""
    Else
        Set objRegExpr = New regexp

        objRegExpr.Pattern = "([A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{2})"
        objRegExpr.Global = True
        objRegExpr.IgnoreCase = True

        Set colMatches = objRegExpr.Execute(text)

        del = colMatches(1)
        txt = Split(text, del)
        GetLatest = txt(0)
    End If
End Function
```

Running this function in the Immediate window, I get the expected results but when I run the same function in a query, I get `invalid procedure or argument` pointing at this line `del = colMatches(1)`. What am I missing?

Comment: If you vote me down, please do comment.

Answer (score 0):

To extract what you capture you want the 1st item which is index 0 not 1;

```
del = colMatches.Item(0)
```

Or an alternative avoiding the regexp object;

```
if ucase$(text) like "[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[0-9][0-9]*" then GetLatest = left$(text,6)
```

Comment: After trying out your suggestion, nothing is being returned now.